# post image on Facebook using FBConnect

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5

I want to post image on facebook using fbconnect.

I have written following lines of code but what should I change to my code to post image on facebook.

```
- (void) postOnPage
{
    [self saveAccessTokenKeyInfo];

    NSString *imgStr=@"hello";

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Hat Application", @"name",
                                   @"http://www.idhats.com/", @"link",
                                   @"HatApp", @"caption",
                                   imgStr, @"picture",
                                   nil];

    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}
```

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)uploadPhoto{
NSMutableDictionary *args = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture1.jpg"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 10);
//NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
NSString *imgstr = [data base64Encoding];
//NSString *imgstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//[args setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"antartica1.png"] forKey:@"image"];   
[args setObject:imgstr forKey:@"image"];    // 'images' is an array of 'UIImage' objects
uploadimgrequest = [FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self];
[uploadimgrequest call:@"photos.upload" params:args dataParam:data];
//[uploadimgrequest call:@"photos.upload" params:args];
}

-(NSString *)Base64Encode:(NSData *)data{
//Point to start of the data and set buffer sizes
int inLength = [data length];
int outLength = ((((inLength * 4)/3)/4)*4) + (((inLength * 4)/3)%4 ? 4 : 0);
const char *inputBuffer = [data bytes];
char *outputBuffer = malloc(outLength);
outputBuffer[outLength] = 0;

//64 digit code
static char Encode[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

//start the count
int cycle = 0;
int inpos = 0;
int outpos = 0;
char temp;

//Pad the last to bytes, the outbuffer must always be a multiple of 4
outputBuffer[outLength-1] = '=';
outputBuffer[outLength-2] = '=';

/* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64
 Text content   M           a           n
 ASCII          77          97          110
 8 Bit pattern  01001101    01100001    01101110

 6 Bit pattern  010011  010110  000101  101110
 Index          19      22      5       46
 Base64-encoded T       W       F       u
 */


while (inpos < inLength){
    switch (cycle) {
        case 0:
            outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xFC)>>2];
            cycle = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            temp = (inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x03)<<4;
            outputBuffer[outpos] = Encode[temp];
            cycle = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[temp|(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xF0)>> 4];
            temp = (inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x0F)<<2;
            outputBuffer[outpos] = Encode[temp];
            cycle = 3;                  
            break;
        case 3:
            outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[temp|(inputBuffer[inpos]&0xC0)>>6];
            cycle = 4;
            break;
        case 4:
            outputBuffer[outpos++] = Encode[inputBuffer[inpos++]&0x3f];
            cycle = 0;
            break;                          
        default:
            cycle = 0;
            break;
    }
}
NSString *pictemp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:outputBuffer];
free(outputBuffer); 
return pictemp;
}
```

Comment: It gives error on NSString *imgstr = [data base64Encoding]; line about base64Encoding method not found and generates warning uploadimgrequest = [FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self]; requestWithDelegate not found

Comment: now i have updated the answer including Base64Encoding method